# React Todo List app I have a problem implementing the delete functionality

Tags: reactjs

I would appreciate it if you tell me what my error is and how I should be able to delete tasks by id!

Code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([ ]);
  const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setNewTask(event.target.value);
  }

  const handleAdd = () => {
    const task = {
      id: tasks.length === 0 ? 1 : tasks[tasks.length-1].id +1,
      name: newTask
      
    }
    const newArr = [...tasks, task]
    setTasks(newArr)
  }

  const handleDelete = (id) => {

    const checkFunction = () => {
      return tasks[tasks.length-1].id!=id
    };

    tasks.filter(checkFunction) 

  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">

     <div className='add-task'>
      <input placeholder='What are you going to do today?' onChange={handleChange}></input>
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add Task</button>
     </div>
       
        
     <div className='tasks-list'>  
        {tasks.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <h1>{item.name}</h1>
              <button onClick={() => {handleDelete(item.id)}}>Delete</button>
            </div>
          )
        })}
     </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I don't know how to make the tasks.filter() to work. It should receive a boolean, right? But I don't know how to implement the logic. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would appreciate it if you tell me what my error is and how I should be able to delete tasks by id!

The `checkFunction` barely makes sense since it checks in every iteration of `filter` function only one static element (that is the last one item in the `tasks` array).

```
tasks[tasks.length-1].id!=id
```

Also you are not updating the state with new, filtered array.

```
tasks.filter(checkFunction) // filter does not mutate the original array
```

Just filter the `tasks` array, check in every iteration if currently looped element `id` equals to the `id` argument and save the new value to the state.

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
   setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id); 
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-lovelace-q6dznc

Comment: Thank you a lot! I am really new at React. Can you suggest me some study materials?

Comment: @AtanasG React official docs would be a good start :)